# How to configure Zuul as a proxy for an Eureka Service Mesh

Tags: spring-boot, reverse-proxy, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

We have a Service Mesh with Eureka Server and multiple Services implemented with Eureka Client.

[Updated Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk1Dq.jpg)
[Show Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1yR9.png)

The service MY-SERVICE is going to be installed in a DMZ (open.net), without direct access to the Servers in the Intranet (closed.net). There is a Relay configured in the firewall to reach an Apache Load Balancer in the Intranet. This Load Balancer has several mod_proxy entries for each Service in the Service Mesh, which can be reached via the URLs https://loadbalancer/

Now I can call any of these Services through the Apache Load Balancer behind the Firewall via `https://loadbalancer/SERVICE-EUREKA/eureka/`, `https://loadbalancer/SERVICE-OAUTH/` and `https://loadbalancer/SERVICE-I-NEED` (running on `server1.closed.net` and `server2.closed.net`)

I can configure my Eureka Client in its application.properties to query the Eureka Service Registry and the OAuth Service just through the Proxy/Load Balancer.

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=https://loadbalancer/SERVICE-EUREKA/eureka/
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=https://loadbalancer/SERVICE-OAUTH/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=https://loadbalancer/SERVICE-OAUTH/oauth/authorize
```

The problem I have is that the Eureka Service Registry response contains server names behind the Load Balancer, which I cannot reach from the Client.

```
<application>
  <name>SERVICE-I-NEED</name>
  <instance>
    <instanceId>server1.close.net:service-i-need:8765</instanceId>
    <hostName>server1.close.net</hostName>
    <app>SERVICE-I-NEED</app>
    <ipAddr>172.0.0.1</ipAddr>
    <status>UP</status>
    <overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
    <port enabled="false">8765</port>
    <securePort enabled="true">8765</securePort>
    <countryId>1</countryId>
    <dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
      <name>ClosedNet</name>
    </dataCenterInfo>
    <leaseInfo>
      <renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
      <durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
      <registrationTimestamp>1596457250179</registrationTimestamp>
      <lastRenewalTimestamp>1596807396087</lastRenewalTimestamp>
      <evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
      <serviceUpTimestamp>1596457250179</serviceUpTimestamp>
    </leaseInfo>
    <metadata>
      <management.context-path>/actuator</management.context-path>
      <management.port>8765</management.port>
    </metadata>
    <homePageUrl>http://server1.close.net:8765/</homePageUrl>
    <statusPageUrl>http://server1.close.net:8765/actuator/info</statusPageUrl>
    <healthCheckUrl>http://server1.close.net:8765/actuator/health</healthCheckUrl>
    <secureHealthCheckUrl>https://server1.close.net:8765/actuator/health</secureHealthCheckUrl>
    <vipAddress>service-i-need</vipAddress>
    <secureVipAddress>service-i-need</secureVipAddress>
    <isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
    <lastUpdatedTimestamp>1596457250179</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
<lastDirtyTimestamp>1596457247478</lastDirtyTimestamp>
<actionType>ADDED</actionType>
```

...

How do I rewrite the metadata in the Eureka Service Registry response to my Discovery request to be valid for my service MY-SERVICE in the DMZ so that the subsequent Connect to the service SERVICE-I-NEED is also performed via the correct Gateway URL on the loadbalancer ?

How do I configure my Eureka Client to reach the Eureka Service behind the Load Balancer ?

I think that a Zuul Proxy behind the Load Balancer could be a possible solution to reach the SERVICE-I-NEED, but I am not sure how this would be setup.

Comment: Please check this diagrams https://www.baeldung.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/JHipster-Microservice-Architecture.png which explain how should looks like communication between micro-services based on client-side service discovery. And this one https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka

Comment: Dear dos4dev thanks for the diagram and article on baeldung which I have read. Problem I have is that the Registry, Service are behind the Gateway. Therefor Registry results are based on the domain names valid behind the gateway. The client in front of the gateway is not able to access these services directly and the results of the registry do not point the client to the gateway but directly to the services.

Comment: is't possible to repeat the problem in simple github project?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the "simple" github project would be required to run on two machines (to simulate open.net and closed.net) and have a firewall and a loadbalancer configuration in between.
I think this should be a pretty generic pattern / problem, how would a Eureka Service mesh (in Intranet) be called normally from within another network (e.g. DMZ) ?